# Android Firebase Query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure
[image]
Now, Im making a query like this:

```
 DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");
        myRef.equalTo("6991580","ci").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ...
```

I was expecting the second node as result.. Then I get:

> DataSnapshot { key = users, value = null }

So, what is wrong with this query? or maybe Im doing something wrong?

Best regards and thanks for reply.

Comment: Can you try using a query like  this: myRef. orderByChild("ci").equalTo("6991580") instead...it sems there are some inconsistencies while using the query the way you do

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to tell Firebase what child property you want to order/filter on:

```
myRef.orderByChild("ci").equalTo("6991580").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...
```

The other format of ordering is a commonly misunderstood version. I'd recommend simply staying away from it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I keep learning the same thing again and again from you @Frank

Comment: how can i set more than one filter? like if i want to fetch user from perticular country,state,city..i have three spinner

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solve it by changing listener:

`myRef.orderByChild("ci").equalTo("6991580").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {}`