# Update value of key in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Having Firebase RealTime Database in Firebase application having web and android as client. Inserting values to the database by using `push()` method which generates random key and all the sub key value pairs are stored in the child by the web client. Now, I want to update some key value pairs of particular child by android. For example

```
KHSIHJKJBNJXKCB -
     name="xyz"
     age=19
JHGISFUSHFIJDSF -
     name="abc"
     age=20
```

How to update "age" attribute of particular key, by not using the key `KJHUJHDFIUSH` etc. just something like update age to 25 where name is "abc".

UPDATE

[image: reference heirarchy]

where "student 0" is replaced by some random values generated by Firabase. So I want to change the value "isCertificateReady" to false. How can I refer to the specific node while not knowing the key of the node. For this example we can use contact number as unique id.

The code which I used to solve the problem or get the things working on getting answer

```
coachingDatabaseReference.orderByChild("contactNumber")
    .equalTo(contactNumber)
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            coachingDatabaseReference.child(key)
                .child("isCertificateReady")
                .setValue(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you have to use Query
Like in Android
`myRef.orderByChild("age").equalTo("20").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...`
[Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579872/android-firebase-query)

then you can call for its *key* using `datasnapshot.getKey()`
and then update the value
[Update Specific Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315353/update-specific-keys-using-firebase-for-android)

Comment: I can not get the key. The Listener never gets any call. Because In fact there is no value change so the listener would not get any call.

Comment: @DushyantSuthar are you even doing it correctly? There are tons of solution on stack to take a look on. Could you show your implementation with code.

Comment: @DushyantSuthar if there is no current value, a *value* listener will be invoked with an empty/null snapshot. If that doesn't work for you, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: n it does get called for every single time you launch the activity or whatever that code is on.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added some more things. I hope I would work. Thank you for considering it.

Comment: The solution is literally what Sahaj says in this answer. If you're having problems making that work, the only way to help you further is if you share the [minimal code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Add some unique id to your student object if the name is not unique.
If we assume the name is unique, then it is safe to run a transaction and update specific values inside as below.

```
myRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo("abc").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        Student s = mutableData.getValue(Student.class);
        if (s == null) {
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        s.setAge(20);
        // Set value and report transaction success
        mutableData.setValue(s);
        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Transaction completed
        Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```